# Simple way to decrease values without making a new attribute?

Tags: python, attributes, instantiation

I'm making a program where you're firing a 'blaster', and I have 5 ammo. I'm blasting an alien who has 5 health. At the end I instantiate the player and make him blast 6 times to check that the program works correctly. But the way I've done it makes it so that the amount won't decrease. Is there an easy fix to this, or do I just have to make a new attribute for ammo and health? Here's what I have:

```
class Player(object):
""" A player in a shooter game. """
def blast(self, enemy, ammo=5):
    if ammo>=1:
        ammo-=1
        print "You have blasted the alien."
        print "You have", ammo, "ammunition left."
        enemy.die(5)
    else:
        print "You are out of ammunition!"


class Alien(object):
    """ An alien in a shooter game. """
    def die(self, health=5):
        if health>=1:
            health-=1
            print "The alien is wounded. He now has", health, "health left."
        elif health==0:
            health-=1
            print "The alien gasps and says, 'Oh, this is it.  This is the big one. \n" \
                  "Yes, it's getting dark now.  Tell my 1.6 million larvae that I loved them... \n" \
                  "Good-bye, cruel universe.'"
        else:
            print "The alien's corpse sits up momentarily and says, 'No need to blast me, I'm dead already!"

# main
print "\t\tDeath of an Alien\n"

hero = Player()
invader = Alien()
hero.blast(invader)
hero.blast(invader)
hero.blast(invader)
hero.blast(invader)
hero.blast(invader)
hero.blast(invader)

raw_input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep track of the alien's health.  All you're doing now is decrementing the "health" local variable in the Alien.die function.

Here's a little snippet that should help get you going in the right direction:

```
class Alien(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.health = 5
    def do_damage(self, amount):
        self.health -= amount
```

Similar tracking required for player's ammo.

Answer (score 6):

Think about it: the amount of ammunition available is part of a player's state.  An object's state is best represented as instance variables of that object.  So you should **not** have `ammo` as an argument to `blast` -- it should be `self.ammo` in that method, initialized to 5 or whatever in the `__init__` you forgot to code;-).

It's not a matter of seeking for fancy workarounds to hide and stash that state somewhere else -- it's a matter of doing things in the simplest, most straightforward, most effective way.  Why would you **ever** want anything but such a way?!

Answer (score 1):

I just modify the above program by making 2 attributes named ammo and health. 
I think they make program so easy. Try it for various outcomes by changing attributes' initial values.

```
class Player(object):
""" A player in a shooter game. """ 
def __init__(self, ammo):
    self.ammo = ammo

def blast(self, enemy):
    if enemy.health > 0:
        if self.ammo > 0:
            print "The player has blasted the alien.\n"
            print "The player has", self.ammo, "ammunition left."
            enemy.die()  
        elif self.ammo == 0:
            print "The player can't blast the alien because he is out of ammunition.\n"
        self.ammo -= 1

class Alien(object):
""" An alien in a shooter game. """ 
def __init__(self, health):
    self.health = health

def die(self):
    if self.health > 0:
        self.health -= 1
        print "The alien is wounded. He now has", self.health, "health left.\n"
    if self.health == 0:
        self.health -= 1
        print "The alien gasps and says, 'Oh, this is it. This is the big one. \n"\
          "Yes, it's getting dark now. Tell my 1.6 million larvae that I "\
          "loved them...\nGood-bye, cruel universe.'\n"
    elif self.health < 0:
        print "The alien's corpse sits up momentarily and says, 'No need to blast me, I'm dead already!"

print "\t\tDeath of an Alien\n"
hero = Player(6)
invader = Alien(3)
blast = int(raw_input("How many times do you want to blast the alien? "))
for cnt in range(blast - 1):
    hero.blast(invader)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to do something like this:

```
class Player:

   def __init__(self, ammo=5):
      self.ammo=ammo

   def blast(self, enemy):
      if self.ammo>0:
         self.ammo-=1
         enemy.die(5)
      else:
         print "U are out of ammunition!"
```

You need to use `self.health` for the alien as well.

Answer (score 0):

In `class Player` in the method named `blast()` your references to to `ammo` are incorrect. You want to refer to `self.ammo` in all cases within that function/method definition.

Furthermore you should probably (almost certainly) define an `__init__` method to set the starting ammunition value to 5 (and perhaps later provide a `reload()` method to set `self.ammo` back up to 5 ... and so on.